# Get the last message from each conversation

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have table for messages which contains `id, sender_id, receiver_id, message and conversation_id`

(I connected them by conversation_id, which they make by sending first message and if someone is replying, first he search conversation_id from messages where he is receiver and guy where is he replying is sender and by that send message with same conversation_id)

Now in messages list I want to output one just one last row per different `conversation_id` where `sender_id='$my_id' OR receiver_id='$my_id'`

I am using `DISTINCT` but I get all rows always as output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id, sender_id, message 
FROM messages 
WHERE receiver_id='$my_id' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: you can use LIMIT 1 if you want last 1 record.

Comment: Just `LIMIT 1` bro.

Comment: How do you define **last row** for each conversation? Is it identified by the row having max value of `id`?

Comment: @1000111 Like if I have 20 rows for conversation between me and you and i have 30 rows for conversation between me and someonee else
And if I say  mine and tours conversation_id is same in every 20 rows and it is like 333 and for my other conversation it is 444 I want to get last row with highest  id thats why I use ORDER BY id DESC and to output only one row per conversation_id. One for our conversation_id='333' and one for ='444'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give the following query a try:

```
SELECT 
M.*
FROM messages M
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(id) AS last_id_of_conversation,
    conversation_id
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) AS t
ON M.id = last_id_of_conversation
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT 
 MAX(id) AS last_id_of_conversation,
 conversation_id
FROM messages
GROUP BY conversation_id;
```

This inner query will generate an output where there will be one row for each `conversation_id` along with the last `id` value (or max `id`) of the conversation.

Later make an inner join between your main table (`messages`) and the result returned by the **inner query** on matching `id`. I hope `id` is `primary key`. If so, then the above query ensures to bring a single row (more specifically the row having the last message) for each conversation.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
M.*
FROM messages M
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(id) AS last_id_of_conversation,
    conversation_id
    FROM messages
    WHERE sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) AS t
ON M.id = last_id_of_conversation
```

Comment: It kinda works, it gets me different conversation_id by one output and by last id from database.... But I tried to add
WHERE receiver_id='$my_id' OR sender_id='$my_id' And i got 0 can you assist me here....

Comment: Yeah I just did the same and it works..... I am very confused because like year ago I made chat on same way and my code was just select distinct * from table where receiver is equal to my_id and it worked but now it didn't and I never used AS in mysql so it is little confused but AS is saying save that query as some_name right? and then use that name later... Right? You helped me a lot, I was doing this over 24h constantly trying... Good job

Comment: `AS` used for giving a name to alias. And it's optional. You might leave the word `AS` and it's still the same. Just used for better readability

Comment: Where should I add ORDER BY id DESC? I tried everywhere I tried order by M.id or by conid or by last_id_of_conversation nothing works.
I get on the top first conversation from database...

Comment: Look this code in the query `MAX(id) AS last_id_of_conversation`. It always brings out the latest conversation. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT id,conversation_id, sender_id, receiver_id, message FROM message WHERE receiver_id='$my_id' GROUP BY `conversation_id` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason I am not getting last id from database

Comment: is there any error occur or wrong data fetch by query.

Comment: No, it just don't pick the max(id) why I dont know

Comment: try this SELECT * FROM `messages`  WHERE conversation_id='$my_id' order by id desc limit 1  . and print your query and run into mysql to check your $my_id value is correct or not.